# How can I specify that a dyn Trait object must have a certain field?

Tags: rust

Let's say we have trait and object as below.

```
trait Foo {};

struct Bar {
    baz: f64,
}

impl Foo for Bar {}
```

Since `Bar` implements `Foo`, any objects of it can be a `dyn Foo`.

Now if I have function which accept a `Rc<dyn Foo>` as parameter, how can I specify that the parameter must contain a field called `baz`?

I can think to implement another trait called `HasBaz` which can ensure the fied `baz` is there. But I don't know how to?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can't, all a trait object gives you is the methods of the trait.

Comment: You cannot require trait objects to have certain field, only methods. Your best option would be to let `Foo`require a method `baz(&self) -> f64` that returns `self.baz` in the implementation for `Bar` or let another trait do that, yes.

Comment: You could specify that, for instance, all objects passed in to a function or whatever implement a trait that has a method that returns a baz attribute via `trait Foo { fn baz() -> BazValue; }` and furthermore make `BazValue` also part of the trait definition: `trait Foo<V> { type BazValue=V; ...}`